# Parsing out data using Beautifulsoup ignoring part of the tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm learning Beautifulsoup... and so far my code has been working fine till i find out this tag.

```
oldPrice = soup.find('p', class_='old-price')
print(oldPrice.prettify())
```

I get the following response:

```
<p class="old-price">
 <span class="price-label">
  Antes:
 </span>
 <span class="price" id="old-price-355952">
  $ 295
 </span>
</p>
```

I don't know how to find all ( id="old-price-355952 ) since i'm looking for the price ($ 295) but ignoring the number, since they change on every single item.

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/11924161/9050514

Comment: Thx for your help @komatiraju032 . It seems regex is the way to go!. First time using it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use regex, `BeautifulSoup` supports CSS selectors too:

```
txt = '''<p class="old-price">
 <span class="price-label">
  Antes:
 </span>
 <span class="price" id="old-price-355952">
  $ 295
 </span>
</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('span[id^="old-price"]').text)
```

Prints:

```
  $ 295
```

---

More on [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) here.

---

EDIT: For multiple selectors:

```
txt = '''<p class="old-price">
 <span class="price-label">
  Antes:
 </span>
 <span class="price" id="old-price-355952">
  $ 295
 </span>
 <span class="price" id="special-price-45345">
  $ 199
 </span>

</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for price in soup.select('span[id^="old-price"], span[id^="special-price"]'):
    print(price.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
$ 295
$ 199
```

OR:

```
for old_price, special_price in zip(soup.select('span[id^="old-price"]'),
                                    soup.select('span[id^="special-price"]')):
    print('Old price = {} Special price = {}'.format(old_price.text.strip(), special_price.text.strip()))
```

Prints:

```
Old price = $ 295 Special price = $ 199
```

Comment: Thx!!..anyway to do multiple selectors?? something like these? print(soup.select_one('span[id^="old-price"]', 'span[id^="special-price"]').text)

Comment: Thx!..for some reason the last example won't work. @Andrej Kesely

Comment: no error at all...
Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: there we go...last span is incorrect...it should be id=product-price. Thx again!! you saved my day